# What is the Cocos2d ccpForAngle() function replacement in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to do some calculations based on an angle, but I can't find a way to find a replacement of ccpForAngle() from Cocos2D to SpriteKit. It basically gives a x,y CGPoint based on a passed angle value.

Comment: ccpForAngle() is from Cocos2D not Objective-C. I'm assuming then you are using someone else's code and converting it to Swift?

Comment: Exactly! sorry i thought it was ObjectiveC, how can i replicate this into Swift/SpriteKit? i'm trying to follow an example i saw of what i need but it's written for cocos2D

Comment: This is the entire 2 lines of code
CGPoint angleVector = ccpForAngle(angle);
body->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(angleVector.x*ANY_VELOCITY, angleVector.y*ANY_VELOCITY), body->GetWorldCenter());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ccpForAngle()` is defined in the cocos2d framework as

```
/** Converts radians to a normalized vector.
 @return CGPoint
 */
static inline CGPoint
ccpForAngle(const CGFloat a)
{
    return ccp((CGFloat)cos(a), (CGFloat)sin(a));
}
```

where `ccp()` is

```
/** Helper macro that creates a CGPoint
 @return CGPoint
 */
static inline CGPoint ccp( CGFloat x, CGFloat y )
{
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

That can be directly translated to Swift:

```
func CGPointForAngle(angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: cos(angle), y: sin(angle))
}
```

but the more Swifty way is to define an initializer:

```
extension CGPoint {
    init(angle: CGFloat) {
        self.init(x: cos(angle), y: sin(angle))
    }
}
```

which can then be used as

```
let pt = CGPoint(angle: CGFloat(M_PI)/3.0)
print(pt)  // (0.5, 0.866025)
```

to create a point on the unit circle at 60 degrees from the positive
x-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the edit too. I wanted to impulse a soccer ball towards an angle depending on where you touched in the ball. Going to try it out and see if it works fine for me :)